# Graphic Flicker

Tags: vb.net, graphics, flicker

I have double buffering turned on for my user control.  I paint 25x25 squares.  Those paint just fine.

Next I added a timer with 50ms, and I wanted to draw the border of one particular square everytime it ticks.  Each tick, it changes the color slightly.  It works.

My problem is that I am getting a nasty flicker issue.

```
    Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.UserPaint, True)
    Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, True)
    Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.DoubleBuffer, True)
```

I have all that turned on, based on my googling.  Yet I still have flickering.  I've exhausted all solutions that I could find on the internet.  Can someone help a bro out?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled across a solution.

Instead of Object.CreateGraphics, using the following made it flicker free:

```
Dim currentContext As BufferedGraphicsContext
Dim myBuffer As BufferedGraphics
' Gets a reference to the current BufferedGraphicsContext.
currentContext = BufferedGraphicsManager.Current
' Creates a BufferedGraphics instance associated with Form1, and with  
' dimensions the same size as the drawing surface of Form1.
BufferedG = currentContext.Allocate(Me.CreateGraphics, _
playGround.DisplayRectangle)
```